# Magento: addColumn option to give admin grid <td> identifier

Tags: magento

I am trying to add an identifier to a column in my custom reports admin html grid view so I can manipulate the background colour with Javascript.

```
$this->addColumn('qty_ordered', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('report')->__('Qty'),
    'sortable'  => false,
    'filter'    => false,
    'type'      => 'number',
    'index'     => 'qty_ordered'
))
```

So I have tried to add the following options to no avail:

```
'identifier'    => 'qtytest'
'id'            => 'qtytest'
```

If someone knows an option that can do this it would be great.

Also I can't seem to find a good resource to find $column options.

Thanks SO.

Comment: Would a classname also work? http://www.netismine.com/magento/add-css-class-to-admin-grid-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::addColumn` does the following:

```
public function addColumn($columnId, $column)
    {
        if (is_array($column)) {
            $this->_columns[$columnId] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_grid_column')
                ->setData($column)
                ->setGrid($this);
        }
```

That meas it creates the block with the class: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column` so, evrika, this class contains all the documentation you need.

Looking at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column::getCssClass` it seems you can specify a css class using:

```
'column_css_class'    => 'your_css_class_here'
```

If you want your custom logic to display the data, you can always use a custom renderer for your column.